# ReferenceError while passing multiple parameters Ajax Codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm getting

> ReferenceError: Y1ohe1oTVVG6916 is not defined

response when viewing my console. This happens while trying to pass two parameters via Ajax. `Y1ohe1oTVVG6916`  is the unique identifier for this input.

AJAX:

```
function checktickets(val)
{
var myserial = <?= $row['eventserial']?>; //this outputs the unique identifier Y1ohe1oTVVG6916 
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "<?php echo base_url();?>welcome/gettickets",
data:{
id:val,
evtsr:myserial
},
beforeSend :function(){
$(".numberoftickets option:gt(0)").remove();
$('.numberoftickets').find("option:eq(0)").html("Please wait..");

},
success: function (data) {
/*get response as json */
$('.numberoftickets').find("option:eq(0)").html("Select Number of Tickets");
var obj=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
$(obj).each(function()
{
console.log(data);
alert(data);
var option = $('<option />');
option.attr('value', this.value).text(this.label);
$('.numberoftickets').append(option);
});

/*ends */

}
});
}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public function gettickets() {
$evt =$_POST['evtsr'];
$tkt =$_POST['id'];

$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM events_tickets where event_serial ='$evt' AND tickets_id='$tkt'");

$data=array();
foreach($query->result_array() as $key=> $r)
{
for($i=1; $i<=$r['ticket_max_allowed_buyer']; $i++)
{
$data['value']=$i;
$data['label']=$i;
$json[]=$data;
}
}
echo json_encode($json);
}
```

If I remove the second parameter `evtsr:myserial` from ajax function and readjust my query from the controller, everything works, but I need this second parameter to be included so as to sort the selection more.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one possible explanation I guess.
Try using the declaration like this :

```
var myserial = '<?= $row['eventserial']?>';
```

Please reply if it works. I'm curious whether that is the problem